# UV upwrap is bigger than image

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, baking, uv-image-editor

So I modeled a log cabin in blender (it's all one object). I added a woodplank material and after upwrapping I had to scale up the UV vertexes in the UV editor so that it looked right. Now I'm trying to figure out the best way to bake this into an image so I can import it into Unity. It's possible I don't have this workflow correct. When baking do the UV vertexes have to be within the bounds of the image it's baking too? How can I make this work? I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the vertices have to be inside. This tutorial might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r-cGjVKvGw